# JDBC Exception when enter data in the table with foreign keys

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I enter data with my java program (simple dictionary ) it throws an error:

> MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a
>   child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`singlehaw`.`card`,
>   CONSTRAINT `card_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`wordId`) REFERENCES `word`
>   (`wordId`))

But when I enter data through query in command prompt I don't face any problem.

here I post my method:

```
public boolean insert(Card card) {
    Connection connection = MySqlUtils.getInstance().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    int cardId = -1;
    try {
        String INSERT_INTO_TABLE_CARD_QUERY = "INSERT INTO "
                + TBL_CARD + " ("
                + STATUS + ", "
                + RATING + ", "
                + INSERT_TIME + ", "
                + DIC_ID + ", "
                + WORD_ID
                + ") VALUES (?,?,NOW(),?,?)";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_INTO_TABLE_WORDS_QUERY, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setString(1, card.getStatus().name());
        statement.setInt(2, card.getRating());
        statement.setInt(3, card.getDictionaryId());
        statement.setInt(4, card.getWordId());
        statement.execute();

        // get last inserted id
        resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (resultSet.next())
            cardId = resultSet.getInt(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    card.setCardId(cardId);
    return true;
}
```

and also scripts of creating tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary (
dictionaryId SERIAL,
dictionary VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (dictionaryId)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE word (
wordId SERIAL,
word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
transcription VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (wordId)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE card (
cardId SERIAL,
status ENUM ('EDIT', 'POSTPONED', 'TO_LEARN', 'LEARNT') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'TO_LEARN',
rating TINYINT DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
update_time TIMESTAMP,
dictionaryId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
wordId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cardId),
FOREIGN KEY (wordId) REFERENCES word (wordId),
FOREIGN KEY (dictionaryId) REFERENCES dictionary (dictionaryId) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: As first aid you can generate an output of your final query, copy it into the clipboard and invoke this in mySQL directly. That is often useful if you want to make sure that all things will work fine.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to insert data via java which references a word which doesn't exist in the `word` table. Not sure if this is about the statement or about the data being inserted.

Comment: Table word is not empty and I am sure about it, checked a many times. If it was empty I would not be able to enter data via command prompt. But thx.

Comment: I checked the query generated inside statement and it actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Perhaps, the fact your wordID fields on the tables have different data types is affecting your program.</strike> SERIAL is an alias for Bigint. Idea discarded.

Print somwehere in the logs the actual statement being executed. Maybe there's something that's not being included.

Answer (score 0):

Thnx guys a lot. Understood many things from this topic. Right now the problem has gone. The problem was due to populating tables via JUnit tests and because of maven my tests gone in a wrong order so it was difficult to recognize the real problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can  switch off your constraints ,execute your query, and switch constraints on.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
... here is your sql ...
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: In this case you may store inconsistent data in your database.

Comment: hmm... i think you right, ... this variant can help in another cases

Comment: Something really unpleasant with foreign keys. When I comment lines with "FOREIGN KEY" and recreate tables, the program begin to work fine. And at the same time I didn't change data type of column wordId in table word and table card

Comment: Also I think there is another problem.. even if I enter data via command prompt into table card, I can enter when table card and dictionary are empty so don't have any IDs. Is it correct to enter an id into child table when it points on nothing in the parent table?